# Is there any way to show windows 10 toast notification using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create and show notification in windows 10 using vbscript. i found a easy solution for mac, where i can easily show notification using this applescript 
`display notification "All graphics have been converted." with title "My Graphic Processing Script" subtitle "Processing is complete." sound name "Frog"`

is there anything similar on windows for vbscript?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to show a BalloonTip ? like [Show-BalloonTip: Show a balloon tip to the end user](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Show-BalloonTip-Show-a-1a932c95)

Comment: Yeah  BalloonTip. exactly.

Comment: Is there anyway to show it from vbscript instead of powershell?

Comment: You can but you should write a `PowershellScript.ps1` and execute it from vbscript !

Comment: Please, inform me if you did checked or not my answer ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Here an example to show you how to write a ***.PS1 file (Powershell Script)*** and execute it from vbscript.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,Ret,ByPassPSFile,PSFile
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /c PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
Call WritePSFile("Warning","10","'Please wait...'","' Scan is in progress....'","'Warning'","10")
Ret = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub WritePSFile(notifyicon,time,title,text,icon,Timeout) 
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim fso,ts,strText
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
strText = strText & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null;" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') | Out-Null;" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon;" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::"& notifyicon &";" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "$notify.visible = $true;" 
strText = strText & "$notify.showballoontip("& time &","& title &","& text &","& icon &");" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "Start-Sleep -s " & Timeout &";" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "$notify.Dispose()"
ts.WriteLine strText
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Edit :***

Another example that can get your Public IP and your ISP and show them on the BallonTip.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,Ret,ByPassPSFile,PSFile
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /C PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
Call WritePSFile(DblQuote("Warning"),"20",DblQuote("Public IP Information"),DblQuote(showIP),DblQuote("Warning"),"10")
Ret = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub WritePSFile(notifyicon,time,title,text,icon,Timeout) 
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim fso,ts,strText
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
strText = strText & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null;" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') | Out-Null;" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon;" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::"& notifyicon &";" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "$notify.visible = $true;" 
strText = strText & "$notify.showballoontip("& time &","& title &","& text &","& icon &");" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "Start-Sleep -s " & Timeout &";" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "$notify.Dispose()"
ts.WriteLine strText
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function ShowIP()
Dim http,strJson,j,Info
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "GET","http://ip-api.com/json/",False
http.send
strJson = http.responseText
Set j = Parse(strJson)
Info = Info & "IP="&j.query & vbCrLf &_
"ISP="&j.isp & vbCrLf &_
"Country="&j.country & vbCrLf &_
"City="&j.city
ShowIP = Info
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Parse(strJson)
Dim html,window
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set window = html.parentWindow
    window.execScript "var json = " & strJson, "JScript"
    Set Parse = window.json
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = chr(34) & Str & chr(34)
End function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another way with vbscript without powershell but using the object `CreateObject('Internet.HHCtrl').TextPopup`

```
Option Explicit
Dim http,strJson,j,Info,HH
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "GET","http://ip-api.com/json/",False
http.send
strJson = http.responseText
Set j = Parse(strJson)
Info = Info & "IP="&j.query & vbCrLf &_
"ISP="&j.isp & vbCrLf &_
"Country="&j.country & vbCrLf &_
"City="&j.city & vbCrLf &_
"TimeZone="&j.timezone & vbCrLf &_
"CountryCode="&j.countryCode & vbCrLf &_
"org="&j.org & vbCrLf &_
"AS="&j.as & vbCrLf &_
"Latitude="&j.lat & vbCrLf &_
"Longitude="&j.lon
Set HH = CreateObject("Internet.HHCtrl")
HH.TextPopup Info,"Verdana,12",12,12,12,12
WScript.Sleep 10000
Wscript.Quit()
'****************************************************************************
Function Parse(strJson)
Dim html,window
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set window = html.parentWindow
    window.execScript "var json = " & strJson, "JScript"
    Set Parse = window.json
End Function
'****************************************************************************
```