# How do I run a .ps1 file via a .vbs file in the same folder?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

The following files are in the same folder.
**Testing.cmd**
**Toast notification.ps1** 
**Run [Toast notification].vbs** 
When I run **Toast notification.ps1**, it works. However, when I run **Run [Toast notification].vbs**, the .ps1 file is not run. 
The following is the PowerShell script:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
# notify.icon type: Information, Warning or Error.
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"", "The CPU is hot.", 
[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
$notify.dispose()
```

The following is the VBScript:

```
Path = split(wscript.scriptFullName, wscript.scriptname)(0)
Item1 = Path & "Toast notification.ps1" 
Item2 = Path & "Testing.cmd" 
Set Action = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
Action.run ("powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file ""& Item1 &""")
Action.run ("""" & Item2 & ""), 0
```

When I double-click on the VBScript file, the .ps1 file is not run. The "**Path**" can be used to run **Testing.cmd**, but I cannot make it work with a .ps1 file. How can I fix the problem? 
The following is the **Testing.cmd** file:

```
(ncpa.cpl)
```

Comment: Please _edit the question,_ and add more details. Which shell and what command, exactly, you use to invoke the vbs script?

Comment: @ vonPryz, done as you said. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the PowerShell script it should look more like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Path : Path = split(wscript.scriptFullName, wscript.scriptname)(0)
Dim Item1 : Item1 = Path & "Toast notification.ps1" 
Dim Item2 : Item2 = Path & "Testing.cmd" 
Dim Action : Set Action = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
Action.run "powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file " & chr(34) & Item1 & chr(34), 0, true
Action.run "cmd /c " & chr(34) & Item2 & chr(34), 0, true
Set Action = Nothing
```

The chr(34) represents quotes in case your path contains spaces.  I'd also recommend more error checking, and checking that the files exist etc.  The above example hides the PowerShell and CMD windows too...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3 files to execute those commands, just, create one vbscript file.
So, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557402/is-there-any-way-to-show-windows-10-toast-notification-using-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top),

You can do something like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,Ret,ByPassPSFile,PSFile
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /c PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
Call WritePSFile("Warning","10","'The CPU is hot !'","'The CPU is hot '","'Warning'","10")
Ret = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
Ret = Ws.run("cmd /c ncpa.cpl",0,True)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub WritePSFile(notifyicon,time,title,text,icon,Timeout) 
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim fso,ts,strText
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
strText = strText & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null;" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') | Out-Null;" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon;" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::"& notifyicon &";" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "$notify.visible = $true;" 
strText = strText & "$notify.showballoontip("& time &","& title &","& text &","& icon &");" & VbCrlF 
strText = strText & "Start-Sleep -s " & Timeout &";" & VbCrlF
strText = strText & "$notify.Dispose()"
ts.WriteLine strText
End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also this nifty trick to start any PowerShell script with a generic batch (CMD). The trick is to name the batch like the PowerShell script, e.g. `MyPS_Script.cmd` and `MyPS_Script.ps1`. It even allows to pass arguments to the script via the batch

Batch:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM *****
REM * Wrapper CMD to start the PowerShell script of the same name
REM * I.e. if the script is named ServiceRestart.ps1, then the 
REM * CMD needs to be named ServiceRestart.cmd
REM *****

PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1' %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7"

PAUSE
```

PS Script demonstration

```
ForEach ($Arg In $Args) {
    Write-Host "Arguments from cmd" $Arg
}
```

Comment: When I ran "**Warning--CPU is hot.cmd**", I got this message: **Warning--CPU is hot.ps1 cannot be loaded because
running scripts is disabled on this system.**

Comment: If you want to _bypass_ this restriction - which you _do_ in your VBScript sample, edit the batch file accordingly: `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ...`

Comment: My VBScript brings up no command window, but your CMD script does. Is there a way to do away with the windows?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. At least not without some [3rd party tools](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php).